# How to calculate a monthly average when the month is not finished

Tags: excel, formula, average

Let's say I have a 12 cells on column A with the sales for each month last year. To calculate a monthly I can do a simple formula like this in A13 =sum(A1:A12)/12. But in column B I have the sales for this year, not a complete year, and August is not finished, but I have the running amount of sales for this month, so far. What kind of formula can I use to return a more accurate average?

Eduardo

Comment: Are you more concerned with actual averages, or with projected averages for year over year comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the current total by the total number of days in the month that have passed so far.  Then multiply by the total number of days in the month.

Comment: Thanks. I like this simple approach and will try it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for a projection for the year I would recommend this:

Divide the sum you have for the current year * 365 so far in the data by days to date. That will give you a cheap sum.

sum * 365 / total days to date

Ideally you could figure out the ratio of revenue and you have a seasonal business:

Last year to date / last year total = Last year percentage to date

This year to date / Last year percentage to date : would project the average for the full year.

Comment: I like your idea, but will have choose the answer from Oren, because of my simple plans. But I will definitely investigate this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Easy 2-step process:

I have my data in two columns: Date, # of Widgets Sold

1. Add a 3rd column "Month", and use the month and year function to return the month for each date (format cells as a number) (e.g., `=MONTH(A2)&"/"&YEAR(A2)` )
2. Generate a pivot table using the # of Widgets Sold and Month columns that sums/averages the data by month